# Problems with *ngFor and MatDialog in Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material, ngfor

I'm currently building an Angular website. I create several components using a *ngFor loop. The created components each have a mouse event with which a MatDialog should be opened ([MatDialog](https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/overview)). The problem is that the dialog does not open properly and the buttons inside do not work. However, as soon as I remove the *ngFor loop and only represent the first element, the dialog works perfectly.
Does anyone know this problem and how to fix it or an alternative to the *ngFor loop?

Does not function:

```html
<div *ngFor="let item of elements">
       <div (mousedown)="openMatDialog($event)" class="title">{{item.title}}</div>
</div>
```

Does function:

```html
<div>
    <div (mousedown)="openMatDialog($event)" class="title">{{elements[0].title}}</div>
</div>
```

Function openMatDialog(e):

```js
openMatDialog(e) {
    const matDialog = this.dialog.open(
        SettingsDialogComponent, { hasBackdrop: true }
    );
}
```

Thanks in advance

**Solution**: use of ***trackBy*** in the *ngFor loop

Comment: Please share your function too.

Comment: You should add a reproduction stackblitz for your issue so we can help you https://stackblitz.com/

Comment: Reproduction is relatively difficult with this program because it is very extensive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this problem in the past as well. Maybe this will help:
[Mat-Button click inside a *ngFor with let index = index does not react/fire action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078581/mat-button-click-inside-a-ngfor-with-let-index-index-does-not-react-fire-acti)

> The solution: Replace the form.controls.credentials?.value to form.get('credentials').controls in the .html template does the trick. After that the mat-buttons are working inside the *ngFor again.

Comment: I am not sure how to use it now because I do not use <form>. Can you explain that to me more exactly?

Comment: `form.controls.credentials?.value` was received from a getter whereas the other value `form.get('credentials').controls` got me the direct reference. Maybe you can check this.

Comment: No one can reproduce your issue. You are refering to values where we don't have any context.

Comment: If you expect a proper answer and we should expect a proper question.

Comment: Sorry, you were completely right. In the link you have sent me you also called the possibility with trackBy, which has solved my problem completely. Thanks a lot!