# Button within Angular Material Table not working

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material-table

I have the following Angular Material Table setup:

```
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="getItems()">
      <ng-container matColumnDef="delete">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let tariff">
          <button type="button" mat-button color="primary" (click)="test()">Delete</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      ...

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="dColumns"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: dColumns"></tr>
    </table>

  test() {
    console.log('test');
  }
```

If I click on the delete button the test() method isn't called. If I remove the 'mat-button' directive the button suddenly works.

I have other material design buttons on the form so it isn't a module import issue.

What is happening here?

StackBlitz to show the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgkduw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fgkduw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing `[dataSource]` to an array instead of a function solves the problem.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ezanza?embed=1&file=src/app/app.component.html

It may be a strange behaviour caused by using mat-table in an inappropriate way.

Angular Material Table expects `[dataSource]` to be an array or, for more complex applications, a DataSource instance.

https://material.angular.io/components/table/overview#1-write-your-mat-table-and-provide-data

Comment: Well your answer fixes the issue so thanks. Seems like a bug with Angular Material then. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

In the mat-table , you can use button like this

```
                    <button
                        mat-icon-button
                        color="accent"
                        (click)="delete(row.id)"
                      >
                        <mat-icon aria-label="delete" class="md-20"
                            >delete</mat-icon
                        >
                    </button>
```

Comment: That is how I have it only using the mat-button directive. I only want text.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem in the past as well. Button inside an `*ngFor` wasn't working for me like in your example.

The not working example, where the buttons behave similarly to yours:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-hq5tud

This was when it was solved:

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-form-array-example-test123-2jzdij

Maybe this will help:

- [Mat-Button click inside a *ngFor with let index = index does not react/fire action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59078581/mat-button-click-inside-a-ngfor-with-let-index-index-does-not-react-fire-acti)
- [Problems with *ngFor and MatDialog in Angular](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306857/problems-with-ngfor-and-matdialog-in-angular/59307166#59307166)